# Google Maps v2 not showing on API 19 but showing on API 24

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

Hello I have a Problem with my App.
I use Google Maps v2 in it and it Works fine with my Phone and on the Emulator with API 24. But on Emulator and Devices with lower API levels it schaws not the map.

[here works everything fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OtxLs.png)

[here is showing nothing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WSsya.png)

These are my Permissions:

```
<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission 
android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

My Fragment:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_locate_activity"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.activities.LocateActivity">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/set_action"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:text="@string/set_button"
    android:textColor="#fafafa" />

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_above="@id/set_action"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    tools:context=".activities.LocateActivity" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

and my Activity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_locate);

    MapFragment mapFragment = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        requestPermissions(LOCATION_PERMS, LOCATION_REQUEST);
    }
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;

    addOnMapClickListener();
    initLayout();
}
```

On the older Devices it goes to onMapReady() and says success, but no Map is showing. I hope you can help me :)

Comment: Probably you are using the API 19 android image without Google APIs integrated

Comment: @MatPag thank you for your commet. I its an image with Google APIs. I also tried it on an older device and has the same issue. I also tried the Example Project on Android Studio and there is the same issue

Comment: Have you tried using SupportMapFragment instead of MapFragment? (remember to change it in the XML too)

Comment: @MatPag yes i tried that too and also the same issue. Normally the SupportMapFragment is only to support APIs under 12 I think

Comment: Any message in the Log? It looks like the API cannot access tiles.